# Disable CSRF on JSON API Calls

Tags: go

I have a website project. It uses Go and the Gorilla and it's CSRF packages to protect against CSRF. I also have a JSON API that authenticates using a JWT like token provider (internal), so a user must authenticate with that before issuing a JSON request each time. So the CSRF is not an issue on the JSON side. At least I don't think so.

Here's my code, where I am using a NewRouter for web Paths, and a Subrouter for the /api/v1/[endpoint]s. If I call a JSON endpoint that does a POST, the CSRF is engaged and I get a Forbidden - CSRF token invalid. I was under the assume, that perhaps a Sub Router would not have the middleware for the CSRF check associated with.

```
router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(false)
router.Path("/").HandlerFunc(myApp.IndexHandler).Methods("GET")

apiRouter := router.PathPrefix("/api").Subrouter()
apiRouter.Path("/dosomething").HandlerFunc(myApp.DoSomethingAPIHandler).Methods("POST", "OPTIONS")

http.ListenAndServe(":8000",
    csrf.Protect(
        []byte("my-long-key-here-redacted"),
        csrf.Secure(false), // Set to false as we offload SSL elsewhere
    )(router)))
```

Question:
How do I get my API to work with or without CSRF protection? Obviously, the web paths will need to be protected to protect form posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to only use the CSRF protection on specific HTTP handlers, rather than protecting the entire router. Note that this will require you to perform a type conversion on your `myApp.IndexHandler` in order to satisfy the type signature for the function returned by `csrf.Protect()`.

```
router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(false)

// Instead of protecting your entire router, you can protect specific HTTP
// handlers.
router.Path("/").Handler(
    csrf.Protect(
        []byte("my-long-key-here-redacted"),
        csrf.Secure(false),
    )(http.HandlerFunc(myApp.IndexHandler)),
).Methods("GET")

apiRouter := router.PathPrefix("/api").Subrouter()
apiRouter.Path("/dosomething").HandlerFunc(myApp.DoSomethingAPIHandler).Methods("POST", "OPTIONS")

http.ListenAndServe(
    ":8000",
    router,
)
```

Alternatively, you can use the function returned from `csrf.Protect()` to create your own middleware, with logic to only add the CSRF protection on certain requests. You could use this approach to only add protection on endpoints with the prefix `/api` for example, as I've done in the code below.

```
protectionMiddleware := func(handler http.Handler) http.Handler {
    protectionFn := csrf.Protect(
        []byte("my-long-key-here-redacted"),
        csrf.Secure(false),
    )

    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // Use some kind of condition here to see if the router should use
        // the CSRF protection. For the sake of this example, we'll check
        // the path prefix.
        if !strings.HasPrefix(r.URL.Path, "/api") {
            protectionFn(handler).ServeHTTP(w, r)
            return
        }

        handler.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(false)
router.Path("/").HandlerFunc(myApp.IndexHandler).Methods("GET")

apiRouter := router.PathPrefix("/api").Subrouter()
apiRouter.Path("/dosomething").HandlerFunc(myApp.DoSomethingAPIHandler).Methods("POST", "OPTIONS")

http.ListenAndServe(
    ":8000",
    protectionMiddleware(router),
)
```

Comment: You're awesome, sir! I spent most of the day on this. Bashing my head against the wall...

Comment: Quick question, I tried your Middleware example, but the compiler balks at handler: 
    ./main.go:188:17: undefined: handler

Comment: Hm, that's odd. The `handler` is defined as the first and only argument on the `protectionMiddleware` function, so I'm surprised it's saying that `handler` is undefined. That `handler` variable will only exist within the scope of the `protectionMiddleware` though -- maybe you've got an extra closing brace somewhere that's taking it out of scope?

Comment: Upon second look, I mustve been tired yesterday. In my Mw func, I define the http.Handler as next. So all is well. Thanks for your help!!! When things don't make sense, and you can't read right, take a break or sleep on it.